# SQL 'COMMIT TRAN' not committing

Tags: sql, commit

I'm completing a basic Update on SQL.

I start off by executing 'BEGIN TRAN',

then execute my update to change all rows in a particular column from '0' to '1'

After I'm happy with the update, I'm executing 'COMMIT TRAN'.

Now, its saying it was successfully committed. I then go to close the window and I get a pop up telling me that I have uncommitted transactions open. Or alternatively I get told by someone that I never closed my transaction.

This has only started happening recently and has happened a few times, to me and other people that use the same database. we're sure we are executing 'COMMIT TRAN'.

Does anyone know what this could be?

Comment: Check your development environment. You probably have set it up to initiate a transaction on its own and that one is not being committed.

Comment: So like tranception, a transaction within a transaction?

Comment: Yeah, exactly like that

Comment: Thanks Juan really appreciate the help I'll look into that now

Comment: Which dev env are you using? I remember that TOAD had that setting but haven't used it in a while

Comment: Which DBMS (Oracle, Postgres, ...) are you using? And which SQL tool?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar behavior using MS SSMS. Sometimes code fails or aborted in an open transaction. Then entire transaction is rolled back. Hence you get no transaction to commit next time. at the same time you may forget to commit, and you'll get nested uncommitted transactions.

You can enable explicit transactions in settings. It should simplify you experience.